Is the experience of time fundamental to mind?
There is a common talking point among theistic philosophers, such as William Lane Craig, that God is timeless. He exists outside of time and space and is not bounded by it.
But God is also a mind. And human mind involves the experience of time. As such, how do we know if a timeless mind is even a coherent concept? How have philosophers explained the nature of a timeless mind and how it would operate?

Maybe God isn't the kind of mind you have in mind.

+1 Not sure why this is downvoted as it's quite clear OP is asking for extant formulations of "timeless mind" or perhaps how one can have any kind of subjective experience that excludes the subjective experience of time

I have voted to close this non-question because asserting that timeless mind is inexplicable and not known of, then purportedly asking for explanations of timeless mind, is not magically transmuted into a question by a question mark. If OP wants to edit this question to fix this problem I will retract the close vote.

@gs I took it to mean "i cannot see how god exists outside space and time" then followed up by noting that all minds we are aware of require time to function.

@gs the question is whether a timeless mind is explicable and how it would operate, not that it is impossible. The burden should be on the proponent of that claim anyways. Nevertheless, I did edit it

I have submitted an additional edit based on your comment. Please @ me if it matches your intent.

The closing of this question, and the one on divine simplicity, are bizarre harassments of a central philosophic activity on these boards.  The rational and empirical evaluation of theoretical theism has been a longstanding feature of philosophy, and the incoherence of an absolutely simple mind (minds to think need to do operations, which requires PARTS to a mind!) and of a mind out of time (not subject to state changes) as not actually a MIND are two major rational/conceptual critiques of Classical Theism!  So logic problems with classical theism cannot be asked on this board?  WTFudge?

@Dcleve this board is now full of people downvoting things purely due to emotional reasons rather than rule breaking reasons (which is ironic since you’d expect philosophers to be more aware of their emotional biases). Again, since you’re a regular poster, it might be wise to post about this issue on Meta because my hands are tied at this point. But you don’t have to!

@Syed  -- there is a group of physicalists who want to censor theology and philosophy of religion off this board, and are using close-votes as their preferred tactic.  Your topics, of rational and empirical critiques of religion and God claims, fall within their zone of fire.    The discussion of this sabotage activity on the board has been on ongoing discussion on Meta, and  the mods have to date chosen not to intervene.  It is up to other users to reopen illegitimately closed questions, one at a time.

Interesting. Well you would think that they would be more open to potential critiques of god then. Nevertheless, I’m not aware of who the mods here are except @causative but I do see 4 reopen votes

Our mods:  https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

@dcleve have you read the unedited question?

@gs  Yes. I agree with Annika, the intent was clear, to articulate a possible logic problem with Classical theism relative to its God having a mind.  Your edits improved the question a bit.

Of course Kant expounded this as one of his central theses in his CPR...

I discussed this topic with the AIs and they say they do not experience time.

I'm not an expert on this particular area of theistic philosophy, but I suspect the answer is that God would only be outside the time and space it created for humans. God might have its own time scale independent of in-universe time, or God might be independent of in-universe time in the sense that it can jump around freely through time, the way you or I might flip back and forth through the pages of a book. The point is that even if God has a linear-progressive mind similar to human cognition — an idea that most theologists would view (to use the technical term) as bassackwards — it need not be linear-progressive in our time dimension or scale.

+1 Even Christians are divided on this: https://www.gotquestions.org/time-in-heaven.html

Interesting answer but then this might defeat one of the powerful motivations behind the cosmological argument. One of the points of positing a timeless being for the cause of the universe is that if a cause exists for the universe, it cannot be within time and space. But then one can form a naturalistic alternative to what you just said: that there is a different sort of time (or maybe even space) that led to the beginning of the universe?

@Syed It would be an interesting exercise to take all the strongest rebuttals to different types of atheist arguments, lay out their committments/axioms, and see how well it meshes with what Theists believe about heaven, free will, and God's relationship with Humans.

The speculative invention of a "time-prime" that allows state changes for God or an oversoul, or other aspects of the spiritual, is common in New Age thinking. However, this is also tied to a corollary concept that "time is an illusion" imported from Eastern philosophy. The idea that a monotheist God exists in a time-prime is NOT part of classical theism, as in that theology God is Immutable, and NOT subject to either time or time prime. I have not yet seen any Abrahamic theologians who put God in a time-prime. Abrahamic open theists put God in our timeline.

I won't get into the mental gymnastics needed to reconcile a timeless mind. However, I will opine on the incoherence of "timeless consciousness/experience", which is related to this.
If you think about subjective experience, it is not possible to imagine it apart from passage of "subjective time" (let's call this sub-time). The very notion of experience requires a subjective time interval.
Take a silly simple example: A being that eternally experiences the color blue. That's it. This experience of blue will only be an experience in the sense that it occurs over a subjective time interval. We can make that interval arbitrarily small, but this is a case where the "limit of the experience does not equal the experience of the limit". By that I mean that when we conceptualize "blue" we inevitably imagine a color and a time interval over which it holds. If an experience can happen over zero time interval, then we can theoretically have an uncountably infinite number of experiences in zero time interval.
Consider coherence of an "instantaneous experience": Not an experience E over a small time interval dt, but one that happens at an exact time t. Such an experience cannot involve change, even in principle. In fact, it's hard to see what content can be compressed to a zero time instant.
So, I think that God would have to have some type of subjective time. This may or may not match the cosmic time. In God's time dimension, creating a world is akin to defining an entire function at once, not an evolving system. In that way, we can have a huge number of independent worlds created by God, all having their own timelines.

+1 If you throw a stone straight up in the air, it will have an infinitely short moment a velocity of zero, before it falls down. A velocity of zero means it is in rest, but how can it be in rest for an infinitely short time?

"By that I mean that when we conceptualize "blue" we inevitably imagine a color and a time interval over which it holds." Why do you say that? I don't think I inevitably imagine the time interval. It certainly seems to me like I have no difficulty imagining perceiving the color blue as an instantaneous flash of experience without passage of time. Isn't your claim rebutted by anyone (me in this case) simply saying "No, I don't imagine things as you say that 'we' imagine them"? The alternative seems to be that you know what other people can imagine better than they themselves know.

@user509184 - yes, I am saying that what you are saying as a "flash" is actually taking up some time interval in your mind when you think of it. I think people mistake "really really fast" with "zero time interval"

It is not a "talking point" for theologians that God is timeless, it is a doctrine of a theology called classical theism.  https://tcdecker.com/2022/05/30/classical-theism/
The attributes of God in classical theism include the following:
Aseity
Necessity
Simplicity
Eternity
Immutability
Immateriality
Omnipotence
Omniscience
Perfect Goodness
Timelessness is just a restatement of immutability.
God, in spiritual dualism, is treated as a bigger/better version of a human soul.  God, in classical theism, is more like an abstract object. These are two very different God theories.  In spiritual dualism God has a mind.  Whether that is true for classical theism is arguable.
For most of us, our only experiences of minds are human minds.  Our only experience of agency, and willing, and experience etc., again are human minds.  And all of these require time.  State change.  NON-immutability.  And the other things that we consider are immutable -- numbers, abstractions, logic states -- they don't have the attributes of willing, experience, agency, etc. that minds have.  Pragmatically, Classical Theism has a credibility problem relative to any claim that its God is an agent that has a mind, because for the claim to be true those concepts need to be redefined relative to what everyone else thinks their definitions are.
There is a derivative problem with divine simplicity, because all mental events (which are logic state sequences, and therefore in time!) involve doing operations.  And in all operations we have encountered, doing operations requires one have parts like long term memory, working memory, functions, a processor, etc. divine simplicity seems to be in to thinking.
It is an empirical question what a "mind" is, and what is "fundamental" to that answer is another empirical question.  Empirical questions never have definitive answers, only "best current working assumptions".  So this question only has a tentative answer.
But that answer is that all minds we know of are in time, and have parts, so classical theism is proposing an alternative concept of mind and agency that is pretty radically different from what we have good reason to think is the way things are in the universe.  These are a strong black mark against the plausibility of classical theism.
Addendum:
The alternative view of God, as a being IN time is commonly referred to as Open Theism in current language.  Here is a summary:  https://iep.utm.edu/o-theism/  Among the advocates of Open Theism today are two heavyweight philosophers in William Hasker and Richard Swinburne.

The IEP has an article on topic of God and time: https://iep.utm.edu/god-time
While it cites philosophers calling each other's ideas "incoherent", in it's summary it chooses the kinder word "perplexing".
Generally, in order to be judgeable as incoherent, sufficiently strict formal definitions would be required, and those are not forthcoming in theism (and even natural science have no such definition of "human mind"). And thus the question of timelessness of gods remains as tangible as the question of how many angels fit on a needle pin.

William Lane Craig holds that God was timeless without creation and temporal with Creation. Note that the wording is 'without' and 'with' to diligently prevent grammatical tenses as it is obviously senseless to talk about a time 'before' creation because this is when (arghh!!) God created time.
It is not clear how God manages / managed / will manage to transit from Timeless to Temporal. Possibly omnipotence. Other theologians have disputed this theory on the grounds of God's assumed 'simplicity'.
There is also speculaton that the Timeless God is more in accordance with the B-theory of time (eternalism) whereas the Temporal God is more applicable to creation itself where location is entangled with the traditional tenses (A-theory or presentism).
It is not clear how either God would navigate the Hartle-Hawking state which involves imaginary time. I think it is safe to assume that William Lane Craig was blissfully unaware of the Hartle-Hawking state.
